# Dynamically loading asp.net controls with javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, html, c#-4.0

I am developing a series of ASP.NET controls that allow for a dynamically created sites where the layout gets generated from a class.cs file, the controls then get Loaded into an Placeholder in an update panel.

what I am hoping to achieve is using stuff like ajax to build the screen with javascript.

can you guys maybe point me in the right direction,
my google is not helping today.

I want to use stuff like ajax, json

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client-side scripting language and cannot be used to trigger loading of server-side controls.
You can use ASP.NET elements like  etc., which have `runat=server` to trigger server side code, though.

Through AJAX? Not possible without page reload.

Comment: how would you suggest I load them, i'm currently using a asp.net update panel and a place holder and load controls on the onInit of the page, what i'm hoping to achive is sending a ajax call that create's the list and then set it in the from end. attempting to bind the controls events

Comment: The scenario is still not clear to me, but if you HAVE to do it through AJAX, why not load all controls in their place holders, keep them hidden by default, and then unhide those controls you want to show, after checking the AJAX response? 


Another alternative is do a postback on the page with some query string parameters(depending on AJAX response), and use the Page.IsPostback variable to decide when to parse the query string and load the required controls in their placeholders.